# If else in Javascript: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, if-statement

im newbie in javascript. Can you guys help me on this Dolby script implementation? Getting error on Microsoft Edge: expected ')' after if statement.

```
         this.analyzer = new Analyzer({
            if( Dolby.checkDDPlus() === true ){
            url: 'http://example.com/samples_Dolby.mp4',
            } else {
            url: 'http://example.com/samples_Dolby.mp3',
            }
            onPlay: function() {
                button.classList.add('pause');
                button.classList.remove('play');
            },
            onPause: function() {
                button.classList.remove('pause');
                button.classList.add('play');
            },
            onEnd: function() {
                button.classList.remove('pause');
                button.classList.add('play');
            }
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: Add a comma after the if/else statement, right before `onPlay`. Edit: btw, I'm not sure if this will actually work  :)  But try it out

Comment: Try to use '?' instead of 'if'. So you code might be looked as
`this.analyzer = new Analyzer({
                   url:Dolby.checkDDPlus()?'http://example.com/samples_Dolby.mp4':'http://example.com/samples_Dolby.mp3',
// .... and so on
});`

Comment: @VasylMoskalov Thanks! It works :)

Comment: @AndreanSaputro You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

A [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?:` would help.

```
    this.analyzer = new Analyzer({
        url: Dolby.checkDDPlus() ? 
            'http://example.com/samples_Dolby.mp4' :
            'http://example.com/samples_Dolby.mp3',
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: Yup.. Using ternary operator and it works. Thank you! :)